# Upgrade asp.net MVC from Beta to Release 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, updatemodel

a) At the moment I have a deployed app on live on asp.mvc beta ... but few days ago it refuses to work with following error:

Method not found: 'System.String System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.RouteLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.String, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary)'.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

googed results doesn't give me something relevant :(

b) my next step was to upgrade app to asp.net mvc 1.0 ... but here I have a new issue:
if in beta I had :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection entityform)
    {
        var entity = repository.GetById(1);

        UpdateModel(entity, entityform);
        repository.Update(entity);

        return View("Index", entity);

    }
```

then now the UpdateModel(map, "/ accepts IValueProvider or DefaultValueProvider /");

Questions:

1. what was changed here? (I suppose that the hostng environment has changed something)
2. what I should adjust here not to break already implement functionality ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UpdateModel(entity, entityform.ToValueProvider());
```

Answer (score 1):

a) When I upgraded my web projects I noticed that what is contained in the web.configs are different. Notice there are 2 web.configs, both in the main project directory and inside the Views. I would suggest creating a new MVC 1.0 project and comparing the web.configs to your beta version.

b) I just use UpdateModel passing in the entity and this will update it accordingly if you have passed in the FormCollection to your ActionResult.

```
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection entityform)
{
    var entity = repository.GetById(1);
    UpdateModel(entity);
```